# OAuth with subdomains

Tags: social-tables

When attempting to get the code for oauth, the redirect url is required to be static. Because our app has a separate subdomain for each customer, this becomes problematic. The suggested solution for this is to have a static subdomain, and to use the oauth 'state' parameter to pass along the customer's id, and retrieve it from the redirect page.

This works well when the customer is already signed into social tables, and the permission request page is reached, but the 'state' parameter is lost whenever the customer has to first log in. What suggestions are there to get past this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's a suggestion that should work:

- Keep the static redirect URL
- Upon redirect, get the user object from Social Tables using our `/auth/token` endpoint. This gives you the team ID and user ID
- You can then keep a mapping on your end of team ID (or user ID) to a subdomain and redirect from there

Comment: Thanks, I see how that would be helpful, but from the static redirect url there is no way to see which of our customers this is for without the state parameter passing through (this is used for our customers' ID). This passes through unless they are prompted to log in.

Comment: @JoshuaKirch This is likely a bug on our end in not passing the state parameter through -- could you pass query params along to the redirect url in the meantime?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I was able to get past this via cookies, so all is resolved now. Thank you for the followup.